# find() mongodb document asp inner array element condition

Tags: mongodb

```
//STUDENT collection

{ 

'name':'qwerty',

 'college':'123' ,

'BLOGS':[ 

{'title':'music', 'desc':'party' } 
,

{'title':'sports', 'desc':'cricket' }

 ] 

}
```

I need to print whole document where title='sports'?

```
 db.STUDENT.find({'BLOGS.title':'sports'},{'_id':0,'BLOGS':1});
```

not working for me,help!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** to return only the first matching element of the `BLOGS` array where the `title` field has a value of `"sports"`:

```
db.STUDENT.find({ "BLOGS.title": "sports" }, 
    {
        "_id": 0, 
        "BLOGS": {
            "$elemMatch": { "title": "sports" }
        }
    }
)
```

**Sample Output:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "BLOGS" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "sports",
            "desc" : "cricket"
        }
    ]
}
```